# Why would calls only to array elements [3][...] or [4][...] cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, exc-bad-access

I'm in the process of writing a 2D game in C++. I have created a class called `BitBoard` to represent the game board as a whole, and to manage the game's logic, in order to keep it separate from graphics and input handling. The `BitBoard` class contains a two-dimensional array of `ints` (named `bits`) with values of `1` representing an occupied space and values of `0` indicating a free space. Inside `BitBoard` are functions called `readBit(int x, int y)` ,`setBit(int x, int y)`, and `zeroBit(int x, int y)`. For some reason, any of these function calls cause a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error if x is 3 or 4, but never any other time. It doesn't matter if `bits` is 3x3 elements, 4x4 elements, 10x10 elements, 100x100 elements, etc., only `bits[3][...]` and `bits[4][...]` cause any problems. Below I've posted the relevant code. I just can't understand what's causing this error.

`/* BitBoard.h */`

```
#ifndef BITBOARD_H
#define BITBOARD_H

class BitBoard {
private:
int board_width;
int board_height;
int view_width;
int view_height;
int* bits[];

public:

BitBoard();

BitBoard(int widthIn, int heightIn);

int getViewWidth();

int getViewHeight();

void zeroBit (int x, int y);

void setBit (int x, int y);

int readBit (int x, int y);

#endif
```

`/* BitBoard.cpp */`

```
#include "BitBoard.h"

BitBoard::BitBoard() {
board_width = 0;
board_height = 0;
view_width = 0;
view_height = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < board_width; i++) {
    //bits = (new int[board_width*board_height]);
    bits[i] = new int[board_height];
}
for (int i = 0; i < board_width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board_height; j++) {
        zeroBit(i, j);
    }
    }
}

BitBoard::BitBoard(int widthIn, int heightIn) {
board_width = widthIn;
board_height = heightIn;
view_width = widthIn;
view_height = heightIn;

for (int i = 0; i < board_width; i++) {
    //bits = (new int[board_height*board_width]);
    bits[i] = new int[board_height];
}
for (int i = 0; i < board_width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board_height; j++) {
        zeroBit(i, j);
    }
}
}

int BitBoard::getViewWidth() {
return view_width;
}

int BitBoard::getViewHeight() {
return view_height;
}

void BitBoard::zeroBit (int x, int y) {
bits[x][y] = 0;
}

void BitBoard::setBit (int x, int y) {
    bits[x][y] = 1;
}

int BitBoard::readBit (int x, int y) {
return bits[x][y];
}
```

I originally had a function that printed the whole board out for debug purposes (which is how I found the error in the first place). I assumed I wrote this print function wrong, and that it was causing the problem, but after numerous rewrites I just put the following code in `main()`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "BitBoard.h"
    ...
    BitBoard bb1(10, 10);
    ...

    cout << "1: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(0, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(0, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(0, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "2: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(1, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(1, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(1, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "3: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(2, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(2, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(2, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "4: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(3, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(3, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(3, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "5: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(4, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(4, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(4, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "6: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(5, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(5, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(5, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "7: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(6, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(6, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(6, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "8: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(7, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(7, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(7, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "9: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(8, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(8, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(8, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
cout << "10: " << "|| " << bb1.readBit(9, 0) << " |" << "| " << bb1.readBit(9, 1) << " |" << "| " << ... << bb1.readBit(9, 9) << " ||" <<  endl;
```

each line (when the program worked) would print out a string like
`1: || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 ||`

In this form, the program would not work and I'd get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. But if I comment out just the 2 lines starting with `cout << "4: "` and `cout << "5: "` the program works perfectly. As I said, it doesn't matter how big the actual array is, or even how I access those elements, they always cause a crash. I can put `bb1.readBit(2,0)` or `bb1.writeBit(2,0)` or `bb1.zeroBit(2,0)` anywhere in the program with no issues, but either of those with x=3 or 4 causes the same problem. I've tried making everything within the class public but get the same issues, even when directly accessing the values from `main()`. I've tried changing the header files to `.hpp`. I'm really at a loss as to what the problem is, especially since the constructor for `BitBoard` itself even uses `zeroBit()` without a problem. What am I overlooking here? Something really simple? Is my computer itself screwed up? Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because `bits` is an *empty* array of pointers. No matter what you use for index it will be out of bounds.

If you want it to by dynamic, then use `std::vector` instead. In fact, I recommend a vector of vectors of integers:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> bits;
```

Comment: I don't think it is an empty array of pointers.  He does bits[I]=new int[...]

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Look at the declaration of `bits`.